# File browser does not open when I click the [..] button of the `Form.Icon` property

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012, designer

Finishing up a project, and I wanted to add an icon. So I simply clicked on the form and selected *Icon* in the *Properties* tool window.

To my surprise, nothing happened. No matter how many times I click the `[..]` button that would usually take me to a Windows Explorer, nothing happens.

I tried changing the background of the form after that and clicking the button for that also does nothing.

After this I tried going into the project properties and selecting a resource folder. Again, left with nothing.

Is there a way to restore these buttons functionality? Or perhaps a manual method of setting an icon/background via code?

Comment: Did you run the Visual Studio under Administrator account?

Comment: Yes, and i also tried creating a new project with no results.

Comment: It may not be specific to Visual Studio. It could be a buggy shell extension for example (they can be attached automatically to a process when this process opens a standard file dialog box). Have you tried to restart?

Comment: So you can set Icon by setting  this.Icon property after initialize()

Comment: Just restarted, still not working. I'm downloading a VS Express edition to see if it will allow me to access it in that version.